# Auto sync local files to remote

Tags: data-synchronization, development, file-transfer, ftp

Are there any OSX tools that can watch for file changes in a directory then sync (SFTP) those changes to a remote server?

Basically I want to edit files locally (whatever files, whatever program) and have them automatically upload to the server.

Rsync can't watch a directory for changes on it's own, and I can't seem to get lyncd to run on osx, due to no inotify tool.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps belongs on SU?

Comment: I disagree - I think this is an OS X question and belongs here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only aware of proprietary systems like DropBox.

But it seems like this could be done fairly easily, using kqueue to detect file changes, and running rsync a few seconds later.

Answer (score 2):

RE : ".. Basically I want to edit files locally (whatever files, whatever program) and have them automatically upload to the server."

You're in luck, [DoubleDown](http://blog.devstructure.com/introducing-doubledown) will do exactly what you specified :

[Direct Download for DoubleDown here](http://static.devstructure.com/doubledown-0.0.2.tar.gz).

[DoubleDown download page with more info here](http://devstructure.github.com/doubledown/).

More info on DoubleDown :

> Doubledown keeps a complete local copy of the remote directory you're
>   syncing so all your local operations are lightning fast. After it
>   performs an initial sync (being careful not to clobber any local
>   changes), Doubledown is notified of changes by Mac OS X's FSEvents
>   framework and responds by creating, uploading, and removing files or
>   directories as required.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy writing a script, Folder Actions let you achieve  what you require:

http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/01/30/folder-actions-for-os-x-explained-with-real-world-examples/

The following page seems to offer exactly the solution you are looking for:

http://sites.google.com/site/andreatagliasacchi/blog/osxautomaticsyncwithfolderactions

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an article](http://www.onyxraven.com/2011/02/20/localserver-synchronization-via-rsync-and-fsevent/) about doing just that with a Ruby script.

It uses *FSEvent*, the *inotify* counterpart on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`entr`](http://entrproject.org/) command-line tool to watch for file changes in a directory. It has special `-d` option to react to events when a new file is added to a directory. The implication is that if a new file appears it must exit to allow an external shell loop to rescan the file system, so when `-d` is used, you've to use it with a loop. For example (to check for changes in `path/` directory):

```
$ while true; do
> find path/ | entr -d sh -c 'rsync -vuar path/ example.com:. && echo Updated'
> done
```

Installation via Brew: `brew install entr`.